# Search results missing items

Tags: templating, search

I did a straight lift of the Craft3 [Search Form example](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/templating/examples/search-form.html).

It "works."  There are no errors.  But, it is not showing all results. I can type `F` and it works. I type `F-` and it works.  I type `F-15` and it does NOT work, even though the `F` and `F-` searches included `F-15` in the results. Any search with `F-XX`, `H-XX`, `MQ-XX` (where XX is a number such as 4, 9, 15,16 or 22)  fails to display the appropriate results.  It gets stranger.  `C-XX`, `A-XX`, `RC-XX`, and `HC-XX` WORK!!! And, these are the title fields. So, I can't figure out what is throwing things off.

My search input is ...

`<form action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
<ul class="menu right">
    <li><input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search"></li>
    <li><button type="submit" class="button">Go</button></li>
</ul>`

My Search Results are a straight lift from the Craft3 example.

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL?  Have you tried updating your search indexes and see if the results change? (under Utilities in the Control Panel)

Comment: @BradBell I am using MySQL. I just updated my search indexes.  The results did NOT change.  This one is vexing.

Comment: Have you change anything of these or just going with the default? https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#$defaultSearchTermOptions-detail

Comment: @BradBell  ...the only thing changed is the input, I do not have a value="Go",  I have a button class named "Go". ...everything else is exactly the same as the Craft 3 documentation .   The results were a straight copy and paste.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `defaultSearchTermOptions` config setting in your `craft/config/general.php` file.

Comment: @BradBell no, I did not change any of the defaultSearchTermOptions. ...but I did notice that this search issue is not unique to my search form, the Craft control panel search function has the same issue when I try to search entries from the list.  It behaves exactly the same.